# New database connection strings showing error message

Tags: sql-server, umbraco

I am in the process of updating our databases to be hosted on a new dedicated server (with SQL Web 2019 on it). The 2 sites (both built with Umbraco 11) are loading with the existing database strings.

The new server has Windows 2022 and SQL Server 2019 installed on it. Our 4 databases have been successfully restored there and are loading when I expand the tabs in SQL Management Studio.

I have followed the guide below, to allow connections from a remote connection:
https://nishanc.medium.com/how-to-enable-remote-connections-to-sql-server-dc5b6c812b5

When I update the IP addresses in the connection strings for the 2 sites, it shows the following error messages:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Login failed for user 'UmbracoFrontendUser'.
Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, uint waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, bool allowCreate, bool onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
```

To update just the IP address in the connection strings and find that the site would load.

Comment: The error explains what's wrong. `Login failed for user 'UmbracoFrontendUser'`. Either the *server* user doesn't exist or the password is wrong. Restoring a database with a  user  `SomeUser` won't automatically create a server login

Comment: Either the login (server level) or the user (database level) do not exist, or you're using the wrong password. It's likely the users, and their permissions were restore with the database, but logins are stored elsewhere.
Check the logins for the one you're trying to use, and that the user you expect is attached to it.

Answer (score 2):

> SqlException: Login failed for user 'UmbracoFrontendUser'.

This is not a connection failure; it's a login failure.  Ensure that there is a Login by that name, the password is correct, and it has access to the correct databases.

> Our 4 databases have been successfully restored

You probably need to [create a login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login?view=sql-server-ver16).  Logins are server-level objects, so don't come along with database restores.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I wasn't aware that the backup / restore function wouldn't restore the logins too - so this was the issue!